# Why can I share one URL on LinkedIn but not another?

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have 2 identical pages on my website. On can be shared on LinkedIn with photo etc., while the other cannot. The Open Graph checks are identical apart from the URL.

The page that can be shared with photo and text is: 
https://gugin.com/dr-majlergaard-masterclasses/
The other one, that doesn't show photo is:
https://gugin.com/leadership-keynote-speaker/

I don't see any differences in The Open Graph checks

Please help

Comment: Strange. Tested on my own linkedin.. indeed doesn't work. OG tags are exactly identical, except descriptions.

Comment: Thank you Arnold. I am happy it could be reproduced. Do you by any chance have any ideas of what can cause the difference?

Comment: No, I do not know. I checked the tags with https://opengraphcheck.com and they are identical. But your pages are very heavy on javascript and metadata. It might be that LI runs into trouble parsing that. I would contact the LI Support center and report a bug.

Comment: YES! I found out where the problem was after a loooong structured analysis.

Answer (score 1):

YES! I found out where the problem was after a loooong structured analysis. As we own a webhosting company too (rivierahosting.com) we have full access to everything. 
Compared php settings with a site that can share and synchonised them. problem persisted
Tried with a default theme and plugins disables in the health check. problem persisted
Checked permission on all files and compared them with a site that can share on linkedin. no difference
Started to look at individual plugins. Bingo

On my wordpress installation, the plugin "StopBadBots" makes all the fuss. Once I disabled it everything worked fine.

Now I can watch the football worldcup final with peace tonight and hopefully see my country (France) win

Comment: Great! Congrats. Do you know why "StopBadBots" was causing this? Maybe you could improve your answer with that info. Good luck with football this evening (I am for France too, though from Holland) :)

Comment: He Arnold.. What a party! I have no idea what caused it inside the StopBadBots plugin. I will write the developers and tell them.

Comment: He he he, congratulations!!